# Kotlin: Can't use GenericTypeIndicator to call Firebase Database's getValue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, kotlin-interop

When using Kotlin to work with Firebase database, I can't seem to retrieve a value of type `List<String>` if I use a `GenericTypeIndicator` as follows:

```
snap.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {})
```

It produces an exception from the Firebase SDK as follows:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Generic wildcard types are not supported
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
```

However, if I call it from Java, as follows, it works:

```
snap.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {})
```

I was guessing that it has to do with type reifying, so I did this:

```
inline fun <reified T> genericType() = object: GenericTypeIndicator<T>() {}
val stringListIndicator = genericType<List<String>>()

snap.getValue(stringListIndicator)
```

but the same exception happened.

Why is it so?

---

Edit: I tried to decompile both Java and Kotlin versions using jadx-0.6.1.

**Java source:**

```
public class Randommmm {
    private static final GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> ti = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {
    };

    public static List<String> x(DataSnapshot snap) {
        return snap.getValue(ti);
    }
}
```

Decompiled:

```
public class Randommmm {
    private static final GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> ti = new C12761();

    static class C12761 extends GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> {
        C12761() {
        }
    }

    public static List<String> m48x(DataSnapshot snap) {
        return (List) snap.getValue(ti);
    }
}
```

**Kotlin source (1):**

```
object Randommmm {
    private val ti = object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {
    }

    fun x(snap: DataSnapshot): List<String> {
        return snap.getValue(ti)
    }
}
```

Decompiled:

```
public final class Randommmm {
    public static final Randommmm INSTANCE = null;
    private static final Randommmm$ti$1 ti = null;

    static class C12761 extends GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> {
        C12761() {
        }
    }

    static {
        Randommmm randommmm = new Randommmm();
    }

    private Randommmm() {
        INSTANCE = this;
        ti = new Randommmm$ti$1();
    }

    @NotNull
    public final List<String> m48x(@NotNull DataSnapshot snap) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(snap, "snap");
        Object value = snap.getValue(ti);
        Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(value, "snap.getValue(ti)");
        return (List) value;
    }
}

public final class Randommmm$ti$1 extends GenericTypeIndicator<List<? extends String>> {
    Randommmm$ti$1() {
    }
}
```

**Kotlin source (2) using `ArrayList` as suggested by Doug:**

```
object Randommmm {
    private val ti = object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    }

    fun x(snap: DataSnapshot): List<String> {
        return snap.getValue(ti)
    }
}
```

Decompiled:

```
public final class Randommmm {
    public static final Randommmm INSTANCE = null;
    private static final Randommmm$ti$1 ti = null;

    static class C12761 extends GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> {
        C12761() {
        }
    }

    static {
        Randommmm randommmm = new Randommmm();
    }

    private Randommmm() {
        INSTANCE = this;
        ti = new Randommmm$ti$1();
    }

    @NotNull
    public final List<String> m48x(@NotNull DataSnapshot snap) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(snap, "snap");
        Object value = snap.getValue(ti);
        Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(value, "snap.getValue(ti)");
        return (List) value;
    }
}

public final class Randommmm$ti$1 extends GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>> {
    Randommmm$ti$1() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing no problem with that Kotlin syntax.  Type reifying is not the issue because you're creating a new object with runtime types, which effectively achieves the same thing as a reified type.  EDIT: but I do have this problem with List<Foo> instead of Foo.. weird.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Kotlin,

```
val ti = object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {}
```

is generated as (in Java):

```
SyntethicClass ti = new SyntethicClass();

public final class SyntethicClass extends GenericTypeIndicator<List<? extends String>> {}
```

Notice the wildcard `? extends String` instead of just plain `String`.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics for explanation.

In order to prevent that, annotate the type parameter with `@JvmSuppressWildcards`:

```
val ti = object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards String>>() {}
```

This gets super ugly, but it works. Alternatively, use `ArrayList` as per [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550043/11238).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped. Just one tip, for Maps use the wildcard only for the value like `dataSnapshot.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards Status>>() {})`

Comment: Thank you! I've added some typaliases to make it a bit less ugly:    
`typealias UsersMap = Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards User>`     

`val userTypeIndicator = object : GenericTypeIndicator<UsersMap>() {}`

Comment: Using the [Realtime Database Kotlin Extensions](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/docs/ktx/database.md/) you'll no longer need to use `GenericTypeIndicator`. But you do need that annotation. It would be something like: `snap.getValue<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards String>>()`.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing this line:

```
snap.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {})
```

To this:

```
snap.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>() {})
```

It works for me, but I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `ArrayList`. It works when `ArrayList` is used. I tried to decompile the Java code, and both `List` and `ArrayList` version of Kotlin (I edited my question, results can be seen above). It seems that `List<String>` got converted to `List<? extends String>`, but `ArrayList<String>` stays as `ArrayList<String>`. Then this seems like a Kotlin "problem".

Comment: I found the solution. I put it as an answer.

Comment: I had to add a not null assertion: `snapshot.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>(){})!!`